# How to enable 3D Globe Mode on Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google introduced the new 3D Globe Mode on August 2, 2018 see [Twitter](https://twitter.com/googlemaps/status/1025130620471656449)

Has anyone found a way to enable this feature using the API?

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there's no way to enable 3D Globe Mode in the Google Maps API, that's only available in the Google Maps desktop + mobile apps.  Feel free to open a [feature request here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814) to request the team look into it.

Comment: I believe a feature request has already been created: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111576221.